# Checking out a branch creates local changes

Tags: git

I am having a hard time understanding git's behavior on certain cases, and am unable to reproduce (or else I would understand):

my workflow that occasionaly causes this problem is as follows:

1. have no local changes, have everything either commit-ed or reset.
2. checkout some other remote branch, that has changes since the last time I pulled it
3. New/edited files SOMETIMES appear on `git status`.

I don't understand how a checkout could make changes to the local repo that require any care (commit or reset). I expected a checkout to leave me with a clean repo, on another branch.

What am i missing here?

---

EDIT 1:

Alright, it happened again:

1. I am on branch `master`, no pending changes, empty `git status`
2. `git pull`
3. "new" files appear, as if they were created by me.

> Applications/Unity/Assets/Project/GUI/GuiAsses/occlusion/DescriptionImage6.png
>   Applications/Unity/Assets/Project/GUI/GuiAsses/occlusion/DescriptionImage6.png.meta
>   Applications/Unity/Assets/Project/GUI/GuiAsses/occlusion/DescriptionImage7.png
>   Applications/Unity/Assets/Project/GUI/GuiAsses/occlusion/DescriptionImage7.png.meta

These files existed on previous commits, and they got on my computer by the pull.

I don't understand how come git thinks they are new files

Comment: Could you pls paste the `git status` output? Might be helpful

Comment: could conflicts with the `.gitignore` be the culprit?

Comment: @kenmistry .gitignore is never the problem in my case, as it is the same on all branches.

Comment: @FabianLauer I will post here next time it heppens... don't have it now, as I had to solve it quickly.

Comment: It will also help if you post exact git command you are using to checkout. For example, what you are describing is perfectly valid for the following command variation: git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…​
Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in the index or in the <tree-ish> (most often a commit). When a <tree-ish> is given, the paths that match the <pathspec> are updated both in the index and in the working tree.

Comment: @sbat Please see EDIT 1

Comment: Are you on a windows machine?

Comment: @LightBender yes.

Comment: @LightBender Also please see my answer below (which took us all day to find out is wrong)

Comment: Check the capitalization of the folders and files, git is case-sensitive, windows is not.

Comment: Trying to fix the files is usually ineffective. This is normally solved by deleting the entire contents of the working directory and doing a hard reset to restore the folders with the correct capitalization. But this will only work if the repo does not contain two folders with the same name but different capitalization. If you have both, you'll have to fix it on a case-sensitive system by moving the files over to the correct folder and remove the errant one.

Comment: @LightBender so I am supposed to 1) delete everything 2) commit 3) make the repo have only one folder, say `A` and not `a`, using git rm --cached, 4) hard reset to last commit 5) push. Correct?

Comment: If there is only 1 copy of the folder in the repo, and you have the wrong capitalization in the working directory. you can just delete the entire content of the working directory and run a reset on the working directory to restore the file structure from the repository. No need to commit. By removing the folder and letting git restore it, it will create it with the correct capitalization.

Comment: If there are two copies of the folder with different capitalization, you'll either bring it onto a case-sensitive system, move the file to whichever one has the correct capitalization, commit. This give you only one copy of the repo and you can follow the steps above to fix your local repository. You could also remove the local copy and re-clone the entire project.

Comment: @LightBender if you write an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that `git reset` and `git checkout` indeed by design create new/edited files in your index and working directory without moving your repo HEAD pointer in certain scenarios!

Quoting "Pro Git" chapter "[Git Tools - Reset Demystified](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified)"

> With Paths
>
> The other way to run checkout is with a file path, which,
>   like reset, does not move HEAD. It is just like git reset [branch]
>   file in that it updates the index with that file at that commit, but
>   it also overwrites the file in the working directory.

Quick example below demonstrates that checkout indeed does exactly that!

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in 

$ echo "V1" >> test.txt

$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (root-commit) cc4a3eb] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

$ echo "V2" >> test.txt

$ git add .

$ git ci -m "Test changes"
[master 92713e7] Test changes
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git checkout HEAD^ .
Updated 1 path from deaab15

$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being a windows/unix problem, due to case sensitivity/insensitivity.

<s>Some team member had a tracked local folder, say `A`,and another one had a local folder `a` instead.</s>

The flow went like this:

1. Git had `A` and `a` both tracked, becasue both team members pushed their changes. On windows, both point to the same local folder, either `a` or `A`, depending on the end-user. So there were two folders being tracked by git, both pointing to the same local folder, be it called `A` or `a`
2. local user with `A` makes a change, and commits
3. local user with `A` pushed
4. local user with `a` pulled
5. local user with `a` got changes from the remote `A`, because Windows is case-insensitive, and git-tracked `A` actually references local `a`.
6. the Git of local user with `a` thinks files were added/changed, because it compares the local directory `a` with the remote `a`, which hasn't been changed [only `A` was].
7. local user with `a` doesn't understand why git thinks he should commit new/editted files that he got from a simple pull.

**Solution (partial)**

We had all developers with `a` change their local folder's names to `A`, then

1. Decide which name is correct, for example `A`.
2. `git rm -r --cached a/`
3. `git commit ...`
4. `git push`
5. Now the tracking reference only has a single folder tracked, `A`.

---

**EDIT: The above DOES NOT WORK**

Git still referenced the files as being deleted on every branch. If anyone were to pull from master, they would get files removed on git status. If they were to commit those "pending changes", the files would be wrongfully deleted.

We ended up having to purge BOTH tracking references of `a` and of `A`.

we didn't even bother with `git rm -r --cached a` and `git rm -r --cached A`, but rather just pushed a commit with the folder deleted, then added a folder with a different name `B`.

Today was a big waste of time.

Comment: This solution is not accepted because maybe there are other reasons for things like this to happen, and because it is not complete because of explained reasons